# How can I modify WordPress plugin with update proof

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am trying to modify one of my WordPress plugins but I would like to keep the changes even if I update the plugin. The changes are very minor.

I tried copying the plugin file to my wp-themes/child-theme/plugin/plugin_name/file.php and made changes to it but it does not reflect to the frontend.

Comment: you can't if you're modifying the plugin files directly. but you can use `actions/hooks` to achieve your goal

Comment: You can create a build process that takes the plugin and makes changes to it automatically (either in-situ or as part of a WordPress site build process).